# How to get username injected into html?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a static html site:

```
index.html
```

I want to use handlebars {{username}} to inject a username variable. It looks like:

```
res.render('index', {username:'MyName'})
```

should work. The problem is my index.html is in my '/static' (my express.static()) directory. What is the best way to get my username variable into my html page without having to convert it to something that doesn't look like html? Thats why I dont want to use jade and prefer handlebars. If there is some other way, it would be best.

Update: I would like to preserve the same structure I have (keeping everything in my static directory) as opposed to moving things out to a "views" directory. Is this possible?

Comment: The only option that you have is using a templating language that understands direct html. Jade doesn't. You prefer handlebars, and that's the answer.

Comment: Is there a way to keep the file in my /static directory without having to put it in the "views" directory yet still be able to inject variables?

Answer (score 0):

Then you must have to use Template engine. You can use [**Jade**](http://jade-lang.com/) it also support HTML, only you have to use `.` at end of tag like:

```
doctype 5
html. // THAT DOT
    <body>
        <div>This is jade testing with HTML</div>
    </body>
```

---

> Is there a way to keep the file in my /static directory without having
>   to put it in the "views" directory?

Yes you can use `_dirname` while rendering

```
app.get('/anyurl/' , function(req, res){ 
  res.render(__dirname + '/../static/path/folder') //modify path according to your structure
});
```

Comment: Would the latter _dirname work for handlebars too? So I dont have to change the contents of the original non-injected index.html?

Comment: _dirname is one of the global variables exposed to the node modules while node lodes the modules. It will be available irrespective of handlebars and etc. Details: https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_dirname

Comment: When using the latter __dirname to render, I use __dirname+'/../static/page.html', I get: Error: Cannot find module 'html'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)

Comment: @Rolando This is way to render jade `DOC` not direct `HTML`. You can't render file like `page.html`